# Git on windows : "I don't handle protocol 'git clone http'"

Tags: git, windows-7, tortoisegit

I'm trying to install git and tortoisegit on a windows 7 machine (a VM inside windows 8's Hyper V).

I followed the instruction, but now when I try to clone something I get the error *"I don't handle protocol 'git clone http'"*

Any clues as to what is going on ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are probably entering the command `git clone http://repo/url` in the place where it expects only the url, i.e `http://repo/url`

Comment: If this is it I will hit myself.

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer: the command to clone a repo is `git clone http://repo/url`.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj manojlds means that, in the GUI TortoiseGit, Manu was entering as the URL of the repo to be cloned: `git clone http://repo/url`, instead of the actual URL `http://repo/url`

Answer (score 1):

`git clone` looks for `<options>` and then the `<repo>`. Normally you can skip the options, but with the latest version of the Windows git bash I've had to add an option for the `git clone https...` to work.

If you aren't using options just use `git clone -q https....` for the "quiet" option and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Quote the URL. For example,

```
git clone "https://github.com/git/git.git"
```

I only had to do this on Windows using the Git Bash (e.g. MINGW64). If using the Windows `cmd.exe` shell, the quotes are not required.